# How to Convert A' MM/YY' String in to a date format 'YYYY-MM-01' in Postgresql

Tags: string, amazon-web-services, date, formatting, amazon-redshift

I have column of string, and it's like 'MM YY' (eg. Dec 21, Jan 22, etc..).
How can I convert it to a date format, YYYY-MM-DD, in Redshift.(PostgreSQL)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert to `Date`, you can use:

```
TO_DATE(column, 'Mon YY')
```

If you want to convert to `Text` (String), you can use:

```
TO_DATE(column, 'Mon YY')::TEXT
```

This uses the [TO_DATE - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_DATE_function.html) function to "convert a date represented by a character string to a DATE data type."